# Very high CPU usage of Firefox only when Hotspot Shield VPN is connected

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1

I'm on Windows 8.1 and Firefox 99.
Since we can't connect to most sites from inside Iran we have to use a VPN. I've hadn't this problem until recently just after the latest updated of **Hotspot Shield (HSS)**. After that Whenever I connect HSS and open any site on Firefox it causes the CPU usage rise from under 5% to 100%.
Here's some diagnostics and workarounds

- Only Firefox and HSS combination will cause that, it doesn't happen when I brows without HSS being connected neither when I use other VPN like Freegate. It also doesn't happen with Chrome and HSS.
- It doesn't happen if I connect HSS but don't open a new site on FF.
- The CPU gets back to normal the moment I disconnect HSS or close FF.
- I checked in the safe mode of FF and it was the same so it can't be from my add-ons.
- The task manager of FF `about:performance` doesn't show any clue of which tab or add-on is causing the high cpu use and I didn't expect it to because this happens regardless of which site I open and even in safe mode.
- If I go to Details tab in Task Manager and end task the highest cpu using instances of Firefox (2-3 out of 11 instances) the issue will resolve without any effect on my open tabs until I open a new site.

Firefox won't update higher than 99 unless I upgrade from Windows 8.1 and considering the heavy customization I've done on my system I rather not to do that just now.

Comment: You may have to upgrade.  Also see if Split Tunnel is OFF forcing everything through the VPN.

Comment: For your security, consider downloading a newer OS, such as Windows 10 or Ubuntu, which is less demanding of resources than Windows. *Hotspot Shield* claims to have a Linux version: https://www.hotspotshield.com/vpn/vpn-for-linux/

Comment: The simplest solution is to use Chrome - or try a later version of Firefox if compatible with Windows version ancient point one

Comment: @JaromandaX - Using outdated browsers is extremely risky, the author already indicated, that Firefox beyond Firefox 99 does not support Windows 8.1.  [Of course, I don't agree with that fact in the slightest.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/100.0/system-requirements/)  I suspect a good old fashion incompatibility between the version of HSS the author is using and Firefox 99.  I also suggest updating to the last supported version of Firefox if upgrading to something other than Windows 8.1 isn't an option

Comment: @Ramhound - ahh, I did miss that last sentence

Comment: I determined that Firefox 115 not Firefox 99 is the last version supported on Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks to let me know that. I don't know why but every time I tried to update FF when it says there's an update ready it just downloaded the update and after restarting it nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the latest version of Windows 11 with the latest version of the Firefox, and the same exact issue, so it's not about updating stuff, and you don't need to update your system for this, the VPN configuration has conflict with Firefox in somehow and I found the solution by enabling "Local network" option in the VPN settings > Advanced > Local network, and make sure that it's checked. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I also wanted to add that I had to post my  question here (thankfully) because Hotspot Shield support is just unreachable. There's just a dumb chat bot that eventually forward your problem to supposedly support team and that's it.